# TeamCity - How to set teamcity.git.fetch.process.max.memory

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException during git clone/fetch. I might need to tweak the following settings:

```
teamcity.git.fetch.process.max.memory=7168M
teamcity.git.fetch.separate.process=true
```

But how?

I can use the TomCat configuration editor tool thing (tomcat7w.exe //ES//TeamCity) but I'd have assumed these settings are part of the build agent, so applying them via TomCat seems weird.

Thanks

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity has support for server-side and agent-side source control checkout. If you are getting JVM out of memory errors during checkout then you must have your build configuration configured for server-side checkout, because agent-side checkout requires git to be installed on the agent, rather than TeamCity using its own jgit based process server-side.

You are correct, you'll need to either edit the Tomcat configuration, or add the additional entires into `<TeamCity Data Directory>/config/internal.properties` ([documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties)).